# Call to a member function get_cart_subtotal() on a non-object in config-woocommerce/config.php on line 790

Tags: plugins, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to login into my WordPress Admin panel, and am getting the following error:

> Call to a member function `get_cart_subtotal()` on a non-object in */home/spicom/public_html/adwinang.com/wp-content/themes/enfold/config-woocommerce/config.php* on line 790

This is my code at line 790:

```
$cart_subtotal = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_subtotal();
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you haven't called `global $woocommerce;`, before trying to access the `$woocommerce` object.

A better way would be to use `WC()`:

```
$cart_subtotal = WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal();
```

Alternatively, it's possible the WooCommerce hasn't even been installed and activated...make sure to do that, if it's a theme dependency.

Comment: See my update. Do you have WooCommerce installed and activated?

Comment: yes i have it installed and activated also .... the site is running well....just cant get into WP-admin area .. this is my website http://adwinang.com

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar message.

```
[25-Sep-2018 10:24:08 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: 
Call to a member function get_cart_subtotal() on null in 
themes\storefront\inc\woocommerce\storefront-woocommerce-template-functions.php:80
```

It was due to me having the following in my wp-config.php file.

define( 'DOING_CRON', false );

I'd added this line while attempting to run something from the command line with W3 Total Cache activated. I didn't realise that it would completely ruin WooCommerce and didn't notice the side effect until attempting to view the site in my browser.